# Check value in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an icon component that takes a certain variant of an icon name and returns the result.

```
<Icon variant="add" />
```

I get possible component types like this

```
type IconProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Icon>;
// IconProps["variant"] = "add"| "remove" | "plus" | "minus"
```

How do I check the name of an icon in a component? For example:

```
<Icon variant={"download" in IconProps["variant"] ? "download" : "add"} />
```

Comment: What is "the name of an icon in a component"?

Comment: @kelly upd question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, type information cannot be used in actual code. It is removed during transpilation, and therefore unavailable at runtime.

So as you figured out, we cannot use the type `IconProps["variant"]` to dynamically select between 2 actual string values.

If there is no possibility to access/modify `Icon` code to get the available actual values, then we can only rely on TypeScript in IDE and compiler to warn about type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
IconProps["variant"] === "download" ? <Icon variant="download" /> : <Icon variant="add" />
```